# Big O of a for loop with a false condition

Tags: java, big-o

I just need some clarification or help on this Big O problem. I don't know if I'm explaining this correctly, but I noticed that the for loop has a false condition, so that means it won't loop at all. And my professor said it's possible to still determine the run time of the loops. So what I'm thinking is this:

```
1 + (n - 1 - n) * (n) = 1 + 1 * n = 1 + n = O(n)
```

Explanation: 1 is for the operation outside of the loop. (n - 1 - n) is the iteration of the outer loop and n is the iteration of the inner loop.

Note: I'm still learning Big O, so please correct me if any of my logic is wrong.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = n; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        total = total + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What are m and n? Is m > n?

Comment: @cricket_007 my apologies, the m was a typing error, it's supposed to be n. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Alright, well, the outer loop doesn't run. It doesn't have a runtime

Comment: @cricket_007 According to my professor it does have a runtime, which is what is confusing me.

Comment: Unless, technically you consider the runtime complexity of the boolean comparison to check if the loop should run, then you get O(1)

Comment: @cricket_007 oh that makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any negative number in Big O analysis. It doesn't make sense for negative running time. Also, `(n - 1 - n)` is not just in order `O(1)`. Your outer loop doesn't even go into one iteration. Thus, the time complexity for whatever statement in your loop doesn't matter.

To conclude, the running time is `1 + 1 = O(1)`.

Comment: Oh I see my error in my calculations, thank you for catching that! My initial thought was O(1) for the same reason as you and I just considered the operation outside of the loop. But I guess when my professor said the runtime is from the loop, it confused me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation to describe the asymptotic  behavior  of  functions.  Basically,  it  tells  you  how  fast  a  function  grows  or 
declines

For example, when analyzing some algorithm, one might find that the time (or the number of steps) it takes to complete a problem of size n is given by

> T(n) = 4 n^2 - 2 n + 2

If we ignore constants (which makes sense because those depend on the particular hardware the program is run on) and slower growing terms, we could say "T(n)" grows at the order of n^2 " and write:T(n) = O(n^2)

For the formal definition, suppose f(x) and g(x) are two functions defined on some subset of the real numbers. We write

> f(x) = O(g(x))

(or f(x) = O(g(x)) for x -> infinity to be more precise) if and only if there exist constants N and C such that

> |f(x)|  <= C|g(x)| for all x>N

Intuitively, this means that  f does not grow faster than g

If  a is some real number, we write

> f(x) = O(g(x)) for  x->a

if and only if there exist constants d > 0 and C such that

> |f(x)|  <= C|g(x)| for all x with |x-a| <  d

So for your case it would be O(n^2) as |f(x)| > C|g(x)|

Reference from http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = n; i < n - 1; i++) { // --> n loop
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // --> n loop
        total = total + 1; // -- 1 time 
    }
}
```

}

Big O Notation gives an assumption when value is very big outer loop will run n times and inner loop is running n times

Assume n -> 100
than total n^2 10000 run times

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused as to how you arrived at O(n^2) for my problem. Will you explain a little more please?

Comment: This flies way over the actual problem and was likely taught already when discussing big-O. The post asked about the code shown, not for a definition